# Linux within the confines of a Pi-based system

Tags: raspbian, linux

Earlier today I was browsing software internships on my schools job posting website (I'm a CS student) and I noticed one of the jobs had this requirement:

> Experience with Linux programming, ideally within the confines of a
>   Pi-based system

I'm relatively new to Linux programming (I know some basics) but after seeing this I'm unsure as to the level of skill with Linux needed for this job. I've done some research on Raspberry Pi's (and I've heard of them in the past) but:

**How would this influence how much Linux programming knowledge I'd need to have for the job?**

AND

**Are there any other constraints I should know about when using Linux in a "Pi-based system"?**

PS. I was unsure whether to post this type of question on the Unix/Linux page or the Raspberry Pi page, so to be safe I've posted it on both.

Also if anyone knows of any good tutorials for learning basic to intermediate  Linux programming. I've already found a number of websites/videos but the more the better!

Thank you advance!

Comment: The only way to find out what the employer expects is to ask them.  I really don't see much point in requesting random speculation.

Comment: @joan I agree, and I plan to today. I was just trying to see (because I have very little knowledge of both topics) if some one with a lot of knowledge here would be able to interpret the question. For example, I'm unsure as to what the "confines of a Pi-based system" are but maybe some one has seen this as a requirement before or is currently working a job doing something similar (if this is a common thing). I thought I may as well ask just to dig up any info on the subject to better my knowledge on the subject before calling in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Linux programming" is a pretty open-ended topic. You need to know what languages are required, and what sort of programming. They could be after anything from writing kernel modules to client-side javascript. The same goes for your own learning. You need to narrow down what you're after a bit.

If nothing else, as a CS student, I'd urge you to buy a RPi and start exploring. It's a cheap and highly effective way to get exposure to a wide range of topics you'll need/want to know about.

My son graduated with a CE degree a couple of years ago. After graduation, I pointed out that you need to code to be a coder. It seems they didn't emphasize that in his program. He sat in my basement office and started his real education learning python. He started meddling with javascript and front-end coding with Angular and landed a job with a startup. There, he's moved over to back-end coding with ruby.

The best way to get started is to get started and see where it takes you. If you don't have a basement full of PCs, the RPi is a great tool for learning network concepts.

Comment: Thank you! At the top of your answer you've mention, "You need to know what languages are required, and what sort of programming". The job posting also says: "Thorough use of php to create web displays", and then some minor stuff about SQL and SSH. Does this imply the job will be working (mainly) with php in a Linux environment? Meaning I should be brushing up on my php skills and my basic Linux commands in order to apply?

Comment: If you think you WANT to do PHP, yes. My son and I don't like it at all. Others swear by it, and like most such things, neither side is completely right or wrong. Be thinking about where you want to go in the long-term. This does sound like a server-side/back-end focus. Personally, I'd suggest getting at least a bit of exposure to SEVERAL languages before you commit to any one so you can be a bit discriminating. Nothing wrong with starting with PHP as the first.

Comment: @Paul Warnick, if you are new to linux in general, learning to use bash is a great place to start. It is like windows "cmd," but with much more functionality. Bash scripting can save hours by automating repetitive tasks, and can even be used to proto-type programs before writing it full-on. If you intend to work on linux-based systems, it will definitely be beneficial to know.

Comment: @wahoozie Thank you, I actually already know a fair bit of bash :)